# Is there any tool/way to create/Import all categories and keywords from XML file to tridion

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I have a long list of categories and keywords provided by one client.Is there any way/tool to avoid one by one manual creation of them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not aware of any existing tools to do this, but it would be possible to build one that uses either the Content Manager .Net API or the Core Service (WCF web service) interface to programmatically create the C&Ks for you. Personally I'd probably go with the Core Service - if you google "sdl tridion core service" there is a wealth of information already in the public domain to help you get a better understanding of how to use it.

There's a particularly good article here - http://blog.building-blocks.com/creating-keywords-using-the-core-service-in-sdl-tridion-2011